# Slickgrid paging issue for search - page number is wrong when pagesize = search item count on second page

Tags: slickgrid

If I do a search on a page greater than 1 and if the number of items returned from the search are equal to the pagesize then the page does not flip back to the previous page and says the wrong page number.

For example if I have 5 items and the page size is set to 4.  If I do a search on the second page that returns 4 items then the page won't flip back to page 1 and the grid says Page 2 of 1.

I also get the same error if I change example4 -
  http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

Replace this code -

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {

    var d = (data[i] = {});
    d["id"] = "id_" + i;
    d["num"] = i;
    d["title"] = "Task " + i;
    d["duration"] = "5 days";
    d["percentComplete"] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    d["start"] = "01/01/2009";
    d["finish"] = "01/05/2009";
    d["effortDriven"] = (i % 5 == 0);
  }
```

with this -

```
  var x;

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var d = (data[i] = {});

      if (i == 0)
          x = "1";
      if (i == 1)
          x = "11";
      if (i == 2)
          x = "111";
      if (i == 3)
        x = "1111";
      if (i == 4)
          x = "2";

    d["id"] = "id_" + i;
    d["num"] = i;
    d["title"] = "Task " + x;
    d["duration"] = "5 days";
    d["percentComplete"] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    d["start"] = "01/01/2009";
    d["finish"] = "01/05/2009";
    d["effortDriven"] = (i % 5 == 0);
  }
```

Add this line -

```
 dataView.setPagingOptions({pageSize: 4});
```

Go to page 2 and search for Task 1. It should say Showing Page 2 of 1.

Comment: Thanks winghei. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your rowCount was not updated. Have you added this on your script?

```
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  grid.updateRowCount();
  grid.render();
});

dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
  grid.render();
});
```

Update: Add this code on your slick.dataview.js. Find this around line 750

```
  var paged;
  if (pagesize) {
    if (filteredItems.length < pagenum * pagesize) {
      pagenum = Math.floor(filteredItems.length / pagesize);
    }
    //.. add this code
    // START
    if (filteredItems.length == pagenum * pagesize && pagenum > 0)
        pagenum --;
    // END
    paged = filteredItems.slice(pagesize * pagenum, pagesize * pagenum + pagesize);
  } else {
    paged = filteredItems;
  }
```

Comment: I have added this. Please see my edited question.                                    // wire up model events to drive the grid
            dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                grid.updateRowCount();
                //grid.invalidate();           //   added
                grid.render();
            });
    
            dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
                //grid.invalidate();           //   added
                grid.render();
            });

Comment: looks like this a bug. you can fix this by adding this code on your slick.dataview.js. Find this line round line 750


   var paged;
      if (pagesize) {
        if (filteredItems.length < pagenum * pagesize) {
          pagenum = Math.floor(filteredItems.length / pagesize);
        }
  //.. add this code
  // START
  if (filteredItems.length == pagenum * pagesize && pagenum > 0)
   pagenum --;
  // END
        paged = filteredItems.slice(pagesize * pagenum, pagesize * pagenum + pagesize);
      } else {
        paged = filteredItems;
      }